# Trigger a key press

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a content editable div. I need to trigger an enter key press so I use:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13;
e.keyCode = 13;
$('.my-div').trigger(e);
```

But the above does not work, the user is not moved on to a new line. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `.trigger` only trigger the event bound to the element. It does not actually do the user action. Using `$('a').trigger('click');` for example will not redirect to an other page.

Comment: Ok, how can I trigger the user action then?

Comment: I don't think you can't, but you can append a `'\n'` to the `div`

Comment: Is that `.my-div` supposed to do something _in javascript_ when clicked? That is the purpose of the `.trigger` - to trigger the javascript event handler attached to that object. However, if you are intending to add a new line to the editable `div`, then you could append a newline character to the element instead.

Comment: \n won;t work I am afraid - I need to simulate an enter event.

Comment: Why do you need to trigger a user event. seems like a XY problem.

Comment: have a look at, https://jsfiddle.net/AbKTQ/1812/

Comment: But your code does just that.  https://jsfiddle.net/s8bvjher/.  
 
What's the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/514q4yvh/

```
<div id="input" contentEditable>
    enter any character
</div>

$("#input").on("click",function(){
  var e = jQuery.Event( "keypress", { keyCode: 13 } );
  $("#input").trigger(e);
});

$("#input").on("keypress", function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br><br>');
  }
})
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @panthro then ask your question more clearly... You asked how to trigger an enter key, I have shown you in my fiddle how that is done.

Comment: The fiddle shows how to use enter to move to the next line, I'd like to know how this has nothing to do with the question, if I mis-understood the question I'll remove my answer.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried

```
$('.my-div').keydown(function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 13 ) {
       // do something 
    }
});
```